# Passing data from modal through multiple widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

Another newbe to Flutter here. I really thought this will be 2 min job but I actually get stack here. I need to pass 'Hello' data

from modal widget

```
class ToolModal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('tools'),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('save'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Hello'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

through Bar widget

```
class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BarItem(
      name: 'Option1',
      icon: Icons.category,
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => ToolModal(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

to my home screen

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Bar();
  }
}
```

I know(I thought I know) how to pass data from screen to screen but modal and widget between really let me down. Please can anyone help me with this? I really apologise for this question but I can not find an answer to this

Comment: Hi pskink.....  No... I need to pass data FROM modal to home screen. In my example 'Hello' string when button is clicked in modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. `showModalBottomSheet` returns a `Future`. You can capture the resulting "Hello" in the following way:

```
class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BarItem(
      name: 'Option1',
      icon: Icons.category,
      onPressed: () async {
        String hello = await showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => ToolModal(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You could use a callback function to pass the data back to your home screen:

```
class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(String) onHello;

  const Bar({Key key, this.onHello}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BarItem(
      name: 'Option1',
      icon: Icons.category,
      onPressed: () async {
        String hello = await showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => ToolModal(),
        );
        onHello(hello);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Bar(onHello: (String hello) {
      print(hello);
    });
  }
}
```